# Smartest way to make a redundant SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I need to make chain of query like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE p_101_108 AS SELECT ST_difference(a.geom,(SELECT st_union(b.geom)  FROM rt_108 as b)) as geom FROM p_101_u as a;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE p_101_129 AS SELECT ST_difference(a.geom,(SELECT st_union(b.geom)  FROM rt_129 as b)) as geom FROM p_101_108 as a;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE p_101_201 AS SELECT ST_difference(a.geom,(SELECT st_union(b.geom)  FROM rt_201 as b)) as geom FROM p_101_129 as a;
```

To be more precise, the first result go to the second query and so on ...
is there any other smartest way to do it ?
I tried to make a new table with all the names of the tables that I need, but I don't know how to conclude it ...

```
CREATE TABLE "HIDE_101" (hider varchar(6));
    INSERT INTO "HIDE_101" (hider) VALUES ('rt_108'),('rt_129'),('rt_201'),('rt_207'),('rt_208'),('rt_501'),('rt_502');
```

Can anyone suggest me something, Thank You

Cursore

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve? Could you explain why are you chaining the queries.

Comment: Look into [WITH RECURSIVE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) for results that feed into other results recursively.

Comment: Hi I'll try to be more clear, sorry probably I wasn't because it's a topic that I don't know in deep.
The main idea it's quite simple.. 
I've a main table, from this I need to substract a series of other  tables. 
To be more and more clear, the first result will be used in the second query, this result will be reused in the third ... and so on. It's more or less the same thing with a classic "For each element in tableSub make a substraction in temporary table"
I tried to use the WITH statment, but I'm not able to manage the first part of substitution.

Comment: Actually what I'm doing it's:
TM - T1 = Temp1
Temp1 - T2 = Temp2
Temp2 - T3 = Temp3...

The idea was to find something similar to this:  
SubTb =  [T1,T2,T3,...]
For each tb in SubTb
Temp - tb